# Can I use POST with an HTML5 download attribute?

Tags: html, download, anchor

As of HTML5, in [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) , I can use the download attribute on anchor directives:

```
   <a href="my-site.com/read_me.txt" download>
```

I can even parameterize it:

```
   <a href="my-site.com/secret.php?user=me&password=letmein" download>
```

But maybe I want some privacy.

is there any conceivable way to use `POST`, rather than `GET`?

If not, I will obfuscate the parameters. I am 99% sure that it can't be done, and want someone to add the last 1% to that.

Comment: Why not use proper authentication like OAuth2 or basic access authentication?

Comment: That was just an example. This is NOT a potect my password question. My bad, sorry. Let's not worry about the data cotent. Let's imagine its too long for GET, but will fit in POST. Can it be done?

Comment: I don't think so, only with javascript or a form of some kind, not sec on a link tag with download attribute as far as I can see.

Comment: If you are sure of that & post it as an answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't force an *anchor* element to do a POST request; It's always GET.

for a POST request, you *must* submit a form:

*common javascript style:*

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('form_id').submit();">click here</a>
```

*using jquery:*

```js
$(function() {
  $("#anchor_id").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.href,function(data) {
      // callback function
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```